# SDL2 Window is created off screen on MacOS Sonoma

Tags: c++, sdl-2, macos-sonoma

I am trying to create window using SDL2 on an M1 mac running MacOS Sonoma.

The code that calls the window initialization function is below:

```cpp
Game::Game(const char *title, int xpos, int ypos, int width, int height, bool fullscreen) {
    const int flags = fullscreen ? SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN : SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN;

    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) != 0) throw FailedSDLInitializationException();
    std::cout << "SDL Subsystem initialized." << std::endl;

    window = SDL_CreateShapedWindow(title, xpos, ypos, width, height, flags);
    if (window == NULL) {
        SDL_Quit();
        throw FailedWindowInitializationException();
    }
    std::cout << "Window created." << std::endl;

    renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);
    if (renderer == NULL) {
        SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
        SDL_Quit();
        throw FailedRendererInitializationException();
    }
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 0, 255, 255);
    std::cout << "Renderer initialized." << std::endl;

    isRunning = true;
}
```

This is the code that calls the constructor:

```cpp
int main() {
    Game game("EndlessGame", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 800, 600, false);

    while (game.running()) {
        game.handleEvents();
        game.update();
        game.render();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The curious bit is that it does seem to create a window. I can see the window when I swipe up to see Mission Control, but I have no way of reaching or seeing that window outside of Mission Control.

I tried setting the flags parameter to SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN, but it does not appear to have an effect. I was expecting to see the window in full screen mode.

Additionally, I tried playing with the values I feed into xpos and ypos hoping to shift the window to the correct position. This did not have an apparent effect.

Finally, I tried to play with the window colors (SDL_SetRenderDrawColor) to verify that the window is actually created and MacOS is not just displaying a random filler. The colors of the window do change.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the window to appear in a complete state when I used `SDL_CreateWindow` instead of `SDL_CreateShapedWindow`.